# Synchronize mics audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, sound-card

I use ffmpeg to record different microphones in a single wav file:

```
ffmpeg   -f alsa -i hw:4,0 -f alsa -i  hw:3,0 -f alsa -i  hw:2,0 -filter_complex "amerge=inputs=3" outnull2.wav
```

The problem is that the last microphone has always a shorter delay than the two others.

How can I synchronize the microphone ?
Is this due to the compressing operation?

Edit: Here is the new command with offsets on two canals:

```
ffmpeg   -f alsa -i hw:4,0 -f alsa -i  hw:3,0 -itsoffset 0.01 -f alsa -i  hw:2,0 -itsoffset 0.02 -filter_complex "amerge=inputs=3" outnull2.wav
```

The problem is the offsets don't solve the problem because on each record of the 3 inputs the delay changes.

I don't understand why the delay is changing on each record. How can I set a top to synchronize all the inputs.

Comment: Can you try setting `-itsoffset -0.5` before that `-i` corresponding to the delayed input? This offsets the audio by 0.5 seconds, for example. Or use positive values.

Comment: Unfortunately the delay changes it Isabelle not fixed.

Comment: Sorry my phone changed my word. I said it is not fixed.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the latest command you've been using (including the `itsoffset` parameter) and its full command output?

Comment: Are these all connected to one hardware device (one card/usb interface with 3 inputs), or are you aggregating from 3 hardware devices (3 cards/usb interfaces, 1 input each)?

Comment: The 3 microphones are 3 usb microphones. So there are connected to 3 usb inputs

Comment: The delay could go up to 30ms between the microphones

Comment: I just try on Windows. The delay between my two microphones is even more important, up to 70ms.